# Using popover control in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

```
    pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverView]; 
    pop.delegate = self;  //optional
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(300, 100); // size of view in popover…V2
    pop.popoverContentSize = size;

    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:control.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Youtube link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iykxemuxbk
It works fine in simulator, but crashes when running on iPhone.
I can easily get so many articles to implement on iPad, but on iPhone couldn't find a fruitful one. Plz help

Comment: Dude you really wanna read apple's HIG first:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIPopOverController` isn't available for `iPhone`. **ONLY** iPad.

Comment: But I have implemented it and it works just fine in the simulator but crashes while running on iPhone. Why is that?

Comment: @ManishRanjan If you read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) that Apple took the time to produce, you will see "Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception."

Comment: Not only that, but even statically referring to the class will make your app incompatible with iPhone. Use `NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController")`, then `NSAllocateObject`.

Comment: @ManishRanjan The simulator is NOT an accurate copy of the device. It is there as a development aid, but you must test for real on the actual devices.

Comment: In case, one needs `UIPopoverController` like implementation for `iPhone`, please see my answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14438607/301444).

Answer (score 1):

UIPopOverController will not work for  iPhone it will work on Ipad only

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a popover look-alike (e.g. Facebook app), on the iPhone, you will have to code it from scratch using UIViews and custom graphics.

As others said, the popover API is iPad-only.

Answer (score 0):

A popover-like open source project that works on iPhone:

[here it is](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-popover-control-for-iphone-and-ipad.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using WEPopover framework. Here is the link https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use popover in iphone then try this library. This is pretty cool. I integrated with my ios app.

[Custom popover controller for iphone](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover)